# GoogleAuthUtil and PlusClient

Tags: android, google-plus

According to https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5170508 you should connect with PlusClient and only then get token with GoogleAuthUtil.

But in my application i have backward scenario: i've already obtained token via GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(app, email, GOOGLE_AUTH_SCOPE). And when i'm trying to use PlusClient two things happen:

1. setAccountName has no valuable effect(except it throws exception when wrong account set) because account chooser dialog will still be shown
2. User have to login second time(accept application)

Actually, the all i want is to retrieve basic user information like user profile icon and name having his email and token from GoogleAuthUtil.

**P.S.** Yep, there is http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#UserProfile but it's usable with API 14 only

**Update**

I still have no idea how GoogleAuthUtil and PlusClient connected and how to force them to work together. The only working solution(found in GMS samples) is to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=token

But it's quite weird - you have 600KB library classes + Google Play Service app installed on device and you still have to fetch user profile by hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option **if you do not want to use PlusClient** is to hit the REST api yourself with the token you received from `getToken()`:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

However PlusClient makes this much easier for you because it converts between the Java POJOs and JSON for you, manages caching, offline access and OAuth tokens for you.

If you construct the PlusClient using `PlusClient.Builder.setAccountName()` with a valid Google account name, you should not get an intent back from PlusClient which shows an account chooser.

Also if you are requesting the same scopes (you must include https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login) in your call to `getToken()` and when you construct the PlusClient it should not require the user to consent a second time.

Comment: yep, it shouldn't but for some reason it asks to authenticate twice. talking about PlusClient - does it require Google+ application installed(e.g. Facebook SDK use web dialog in such case) ?

Comment: PlusClient does not need the Google+ application.  It only requires Google Play services.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

"Actually, the all i want is to retrieve basic user information like user profile icon":

You can use [Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) with one tap experience.

Make sure to use the [ID token flow](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html) if you have a server and you want to pass the user info to your server.

For all of you using GoogleAuthUtil / Plus.API / PlusClient in the past, check out this [Google Sign-In best practice blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html) to ensure security and best UX.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to match the scopes of `PlusClient` and `getToken`:

```
new PlusClient
  .Builder(this, this, this)
  .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
  .build();
```

Comment: Hey @ASGM, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: @toobsco42 Unfortunately I'm not the one to ask; my edits were purely stylistic.  But hopefully Iury Ramos will have an answer (and by commenting on the answer they should be notified too).